# Partial derivatives of the hypergeometric ${_2F_1}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative, hypergeometric-function

Do formulas for the partial derivatives of the hypergeometric function ${_2F_1}$ exist?

I mean I am interested in $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\  {_2F_1}(a,b,c,z)$$$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\  {_2F_1}(a,b,c,z)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial c} \ {_2F_1}(a,b,c,z)$$

Comment: [Link](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/20/ShowAll.html).

Comment: @Lucian thank you. I was looking for some "closed form" expression but apparently I need to use more sophisticated functions to express the derivatives. Thanks nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Lucian pointed out the derivatives for the hypergeometric function w.r.t. its parameters are given in terms of the differentiated series expansion
$$
\partial_a F(a,b;c;z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k(b)_k}{(c)_k}(\psi(a+k)-\psi(a))\frac{z^k}{k!},
$$
$$
\partial_b F(a,b;c;z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k(b)_k}{(c)_k}(\psi(b+k)-\psi(b))\frac{z^k}{k!},
$$
and
$$
\partial_c F(a,b;c;z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(a)_k(b)_k}{(c)_k}(\psi(c)-\psi(c+k))\frac{z^k}{k!}.
$$
For higher order derivatives see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231045961_Derivatives_of_any_order_of_the_Gaussian_hypergeometric_function_2F1a_b_c_Z_with_respect_to_the_parameters_a_b_and_c). Only in special cases do these series have closed-forms in terms of elementary functions. Furthermore, by the ratio test one can confirm that these series converge for $|z|<1$ and for certain values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ convergence also takes place at the endpoints $z={-1,1}$.